# G-Suite: keep google drive while leaving emails

Tags: google-apps, google-workspace

I registered G-Suite free long ago for my domain. We use Google Drive for file sharing and emails under that domain. Recently Google seems forcing me to upgrade to their pay plan. They list some of our key emails to spam list so that those email can't send mail to group. It also list some of our partners emails to spam list so that they can't send mail to email group under our domain.
Google suggests that in order to manage spam list sending to a group under domain, we have to upgrade to a pay plan.
As we have many users, the pay plan will be too expensive. So I'm thinking to run my own mail server, however still want to use google drive for file sharing within users in domains.
I would like to ask if there will be any issue if I change MX records to my own email server and keep using G-Suite free for file sharing with google drive ?!

Thanks,
Klab

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "it depends".  Your split brain approach absolutely does work. We have exactly that configuration where we have some MX records going to on-prem, some going to gmail AND THEN to on-prem and some going only to gmail.  The mails flow well and users get their email. The reason that I say "it depends" is that it depends on what you mean by issue.  There's no issue with mail delivery, but there are issues with management.  For example ideally you will have domainA.com for your email and domainB.com for your Gsuite and keep them separate: you don't have to do this obviously, but I wish we had.  If you must have only domainA.com with domainA registered as your GoogleID but not with your MX record it will work, but it will probably end up with a headache when you get a problem in two years when userX's emails don't arrive and you have to track through where they go. That may not be an issue for you, but if you end up with 100 sub domains and 100K users then it's irritating to say the least.

You have other options with GSuite Enterprise and I assume Free, you can route all your inbound emails from a mail gateway see the [docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2614757?hl=en) so you can have both.  Your inbound mails hit your Exchange server which then forwards to GSuite, or you can set up mail routes [doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084?hl=en&ref_topic=2921034) to forward all your inbound emails to your Exchange server, so you keep your MX record as Google and then your forward those mails to Exchange, then you reply from Exchange and the recipient replies back to Google.  We do that too.  It does work, insofar that the mail is delivered but it gets confusing to debug issues. But if you must have only one domain and you have to split up users then it's one approach.

You also configure a non-Gmail mailbox see [doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3028953?hl=en) which routes all your messages to, say, Exchange.

However, before you do, I'd look more into the Gsuite anti-spam features.  You can customise some of the Google spam filtering.  See [doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2368132?hl=en) . You can't customise all of it: we have had hangouts with the Google spam team who (eventually) explained some of their internal workings and there are some spam messages that you simply can't get delivered because the spam filter is applied before the GSuite level.  Most business-type spam, rather than the nasty malware or "adult" spam, though is managed at the Gsuite level and you can disable it by domain if you wish. Differentiating between what Google thinks is spam and what the business thinks is spam still crops up for us from time-to-time.

To address your core issue of spam emails not being delivered to your group, I do not know about the free tier: we have the Enterprise tier, but on the assumption that the Groups configuration is the same (which it may not be but if it is) you can configure message moderation [docs](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2466386?hl=en) for a group.  You can set "spam messages" to "skip the moderation queues".  We have done that where, as with you, legitimate mails get classed as spam because they come from, say, automated services.  We have also in cases removed the "archive" ability so the group is really only a mail distribution list and that bypassed the moderation for us.

I enclose a screenshot of the Enterprise Groups moderation options page from the control panel so you can see what we get in Enterprise and if it's different from what you get in Free Tier
[image: screenshot of Enterprise Google Groups Moderation]